# SQL Query Totals

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a query that calculates the average profit per employee for several projects.

I have a table that has employee names, what project they are working on, and how much profit they bring to their specific project each day.

My first query gives 3 fields - The project name, the sum of all the profits the employees bring to the project, and the number of employees in the project.

My second query I am trying to display 2 fields - the project name and the average profit per employee that each project makes

```
SELECT SAYSquery.ProjectName, SUM(SAYSquery.Profit) AS SumOfProfit, Count(SAYSquery.[EmpFirstName]) AS NumberOfEmps
FROM SAYSquery
WHERE profit > 0
GROUP BY SAYSquery.ProjectName;
```

```
SELECT SAYSqueryNIPE.[ProjectName], SAYSqueryNIPE.[SumOfProfit]/[NumberOfEmps] AS total
FROM SAYSqueryNIPE
GROUP BY SAYSqueryNIPE.[ProjectName], SAYSqueryNIPE.[SumOfProfit]/[NumberOfEmps];
```

Unfortunately, my second query is giving me the same average profit for every project and I'm not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Query 1 reads:

```
**Employee Name | Sell Rate | Renumeration | Profit (Sell-Renumeration) | Project Name**
```

Query 2 reads:

```
**PROJECT NAME | SumofProfit | NumberofEmployees**

Project X | $1500 | 3 employees
```

Query 3 reads:

```
**PROJECT NAME | TOTAL**

Project X | $500 (Average profit per employee)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results.

Comment: You don't need group by on the second query

Comment: Edited my original post with sample data - hopefully that makes a bit more sense. I removed the GROUP BY in my second query but it still gives the same value for all of the records in the TOTAL field

Comment: What's wrong with `AVG()`?

Comment: In what query @KenWhite

Comment: The one where you're trying to calculate the average, of course. Where else would you use `AVG()`?

Comment: That would calculate the average value of the column - I want the sum of the profits from a project divided by the number of employees working on that project @KenWhite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your first query where you count the number of employees. As written in the question, you are returning a count of rows, not employees who worked on the project. You need to use `count distinct`. I'd also recommend not counting on `EmpFirstName`. If you have more than one employee with the same first name, the query won't give you correct results. It would be better to use a unique employee identifier instead of their first name.

```
SELECT SAYSquery.ProjectName, SUM(SAYSquery.Profit) AS SumOfProfit, 
       Count(distinct SAYSquery.[EmpFirstName]) AS NumberOfEmps
  FROM SAYSquery
 WHERE profit > 0
GROUP BY SAYSquery.ProjectName
```

You could wrap the whole thing up into a single query instead of two or three, as described in your question.

```
SELECT SAYSquery.ProjectName, SUM(SAYSquery.Profit)/Count(distinct SAYSquery.[EmpFirstName]) AS AvgProfitPerEmployee
  FROM SAYSquery
 WHERE profit > 0
GROUP BY SAYSquery.ProjectName
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam M - when I tried your first query I got a 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Count(distinct SAYSquery.[EmpFirstName])'